# Polygonal lasso tool selection not copying properly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

Copying a selection done by a polygonal lasso tool does not copy the colours of the pixels selected correctly, as is shown below:

[image]

[image]

What can one do to make a proper copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select and copy an area of distinct pixels with no smoothing make sure that (with your selection tool active) "**Feather**" is set to `0px` and "***Anti-alias***" is un-checked:

[image: Selection Feather and Anti-Aliasing]

Comment: Thanks, this works for the polygonal lasso tool perfectly. What ought one do when one selects all visible pixels of a layer by clicking its thumbnail in the Layers list? Thank you.

Comment: Selecting via the thumbnail selects all visible pixels, there is no feathering or anti-aliasing on the selection at all so theres no need to do anything. If you need to adjust the selection you can use the "Refine Edge" function to do so.